# TestFlight expired

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/Testflight/) (the new one) to share my app.

I have now shared it with 3 of my internal testers on [itunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) one of them everything has worked fine and they have successfully downloaded the app.

But the other two when on the TestFlight app get a page like this:

[image]

Why my it be expired it makes no sense as it is definitely with in the 30 day test period as it is working fine on the other internal tester any help would be great

---

## Update

I just received an email from the "App Store Developer Support Escalation Team"

They said:

> Hi Max,
>
> We believe this issue has been resolved.  If your testers are still
> unable to test your app when using the TestFlight app version 1.0.1,
> please let us know.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Ben

If anybody is still having the problem **before** they try the answers bellow and **after** they have updated the TestFlight app. Let me know and I will get back to the "App Store Developer Support Escalation Team".

Comment: Could it be that you have to upload a fresh provisioning profile on TestFlight platform? It can't do any harm so it's worth a try.

Comment: @rokjarc how would i go about doing this?

Comment: I am confused with the difference between https://developer.apple.com/app-store/Testflight/ and https://www.testflightapp.com/

Comment: If you are using iTunes Connect Beta testing you have to recompile the app using fresh App Store Distribution Profile (with beta entitlement) and upload your app. In "old" TestFlight you don't need Beta entitlements - there you go to tab Apps and select your app. Then select Permissions (on the left) and you should see an option to upload provisioning profile on top of the page. In short: iTunes Connect version requires "special" distribution profile with Beta entitlement enabled.

Comment: OKay but how can I recompile the app using fresh App Store Distribution Profile ?

Comment: I have done this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW26 and created a new provision profile the old one had an alert sign next to it... Is that all I need to do?

Comment: You should also refresh the profile in Xcode before compiling. Tt's done in Preferences/Accounts. I can't be more precise a the moment since i don't have a mac around here.

Comment: I have done all that but still saying expired!! Do i need to add the ussers UDID or something?

Comment: If device identifier was missing then app would not even show on TestFlight platform (for that device). There were a lot of problems with TestFlight when iOS7 came out. The usual solution was: remove the application being tested & remove all TestFlight related profiles (settings->general->profiles).

Comment: Please bare in mind I am using the new TestFlight

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work @Maximilian? I'm having a similar problem. I wish I could find out what causes the EXPIRED text.

Comment: @olive first try meda's answer then try Andres Abil's let me know if you don't quite understand their answers!

Comment: Hello, any solution on this?

Comment: The answers aren't sufficient?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When shit like that happens, it usually means you have issue with provisioning profile.

It is the only thing that could possibly expire (certificates also)

Here are the following steps that will help you resolve this issue:

1. Log into your developer account
2. Delete/regenerate the profile
3. Go to Xcode
4. preferences
5. then account
6. refresh the provision
7. clean
8. build (using production profile)
9. archive
10. submit

Voila, should work fine now!

Answer (score 7):

The same happened to me a couple of weeks ago.
In some devices it was working, while in others the expired button appeared.
If the provisioning profile regeneration doesn't work, it must be an issue with the Language & Region section in the iOS settings.
Just compare what is different between the ones that work and the ones that doesn't.
In my case, I fixed it setting the region as United States, Gregorian Calendar, and Advanced in Automatic.
After I changed this, the button changed to "Download" state immediately.
I hope it works for you.

Comment: This worked for me.

For some reason my language was set to "English" and not to "English (UK)" and I'm in the UK and apparently this cases stuff to break. Very very confusing and weird.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if the devices showing the app as expired in TestFlight are set to use a 24-Hour system clock. On the device, go to settings -> General -> Date & Time. Ensure the 24-Hour Time switch is on, as TestFlight currently struggles with 12-Hour system clocks.

Comment: Yeah this worked for me. what the f.. is that all about? thanks apple for wasting about a week

Comment: In a similar vein, make sure your system date and time isn't manually set to the future for some reason..